# Is there a better way to scan the surrounding elements of every element in a 2D array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix

I have a 2D matrix `A[row][col]`. Let say it consists only boolean values.
I want to iterate through every element. For each iteration, it will scan the 8 surrounding elements of that element, and count the number of True values. Let just ignore the counter process.
[image: surround elements]

```
// scanning element A[i][j]
counter = countHowManyTrue(A[i+1][j], A[i-1][j], A[i][j+1], A[i][j-1]... and so on)
```

Except the first row, the last row, the first column, and the last column, every other elements have 8 surrounding elements. So I have to write if-else statement to check, like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < m; i++){
   for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
      if(i == 0 && j == 0){ // first row, first col
      // do sth
      }
      if(i == m && j == 0){
      //do sth
      }
   }
}
```

and I have to repeat the if-else statement many times to check the edge cases, which is very time-consuming.
Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other have mentioned you can pad matrix with a border of zeroes so there's no edge cases:
[image]

If space is not an issue there's another speedup, instead of looking 8 neighbors for each cell we can actually get sum of neighbors values in fewer operation with some pre-calculation.

Let's in each matrix cell (after adding 0 borders) keep sum of elements from corner `0,0`
It's simple to do:

```
 //lets assume matrix was of size n*m before padding with border of zeroes twice
 for(int i=2; i<=n+2; i++)
 for(int j=2; j<=m+2; j++)
   matrix[i][j] += matrix[i-1][j] + matrix[i][j-1] - matrix[i-1][j-1]
```

Now getting some cells neighbors is just some math, let's say we want neighbors of some cell `x,y` we can get it by `matrix[x+1][y+1] - matrix[x-2][y] - matrix[x][y-2] + matrix[x-2][y-2] - matrix[x][y]`

Now it takes only `7` additions/subtractions per cell compared to `8` originally

Answer (score 3):

One of the simplest ways to do this is to add a sentinel rows and columns: row of all zeros above and below the real data. Then you don't need to special-case it.

Comment: This is often done with board games like chess to make move generation easier to code. But you also need it to the left and the right.